# What is test1, test2 and test3 in case of STUN?

Tags: p2p, stun

I didn't understood importance of three tests in case of STUN ? STUN server is used for knowing external port and ip address so why three requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three tests are used by a sip client to determine in which mode the STUN-Gateway is operating

- Open Internet
- Full Cone NAT
- Restricted Cone
- Restricted Port
- UDP Blocked
- Symmetric UDP Firewall
- Symmetric NAT

If the three tests algorithm ends up in one of the later three states no UDP communication is possible.

Check this nice wikimedia graphic for a flowchart of the [NAT characterization algorithm](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/STUN_Algorithm3.svg)